# SQL server JDBC: invalid object for temp table

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, temp-tables

SQL server JDBC: invalid object for temp table. e.g.

```
select * into #temp from Foo;
GO
select * from #temp;
GO
drop table #temp;
```

This works in MSMS. But using JDBC, 3 statements:

```
 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name '#temp'
```

If changing #temp to ##temp, it works in JDBC.

So what is the difference between executing from MSMS and JDBC for #temp?

Comment: i believe you are referring SSMS as MSMS?

Comment: Microsoft SqlServer Management Studio

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and the full exception stacktrace.